# Gtk application (Gvim) rendering troubleshooting

Tags: xorg, gtk, gvim

When I switch from gvim to another application and then after some time switch back gvim window appears blank with cursor blinking in the middle. Sometimes toolbar and tabs look like a white space.

When I opening a new tab, tab bar doesn't refresh itself and shows the same tabs as before opening new tab. When I resizing window everything goes back to normal.

[image: Gvim glitch]

How to fix gvim rendering problem in gentoo linux (or how to understand what causes this problem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try something like:

```
:au FocusGained * :redraw!<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try when it will happen to me again, it looks like something that may actually work. I had that problem approximately year ago and I've solved it by installing funtoo :)